# Named arguments in BeginForm overload of MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, arguments

I see a overload for `BeginForm` method which has the following signature:

> (extension) MvcForm HtmlHelper.BeginForm(string actionName, string
>   ControllerName, FormMethod method)

And I use `named-arguments` while invocation something like,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName:"Index", controllerName:"Home", FormMethod.Get))
```

But, I keep getting an error like this:

```
CS1738: Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter name for your last argument too:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName:"Index", controllerName:"Home", method:FormMethod.Get))
//                                                                  ↖ parameter name
```

Comment: I tried this, I get " CS1739: The best overload for 'BeginForm' does not have a parameter named 'FormMethod'"

Comment: Apologies; it should be `method` instead of `FormMethod`.

Comment: Great, worked. Thanks. But how did you figure it out ? I tried `FormMethod:` but never worked. did you go through all the intelli-sense and found out ? Wonder how you guys are so fast.

Comment: No, I actually only read the signature that you gave at the beginning of your question. Each parameter declaration consists of its type (e.g. `FormMethod`) followed by its name (e.g. `name`). When specifying named arguments, you have the use the latter of the two. This applies for any method signature.